# asp.net in process memory, sqlite?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, sqlite, memory

Has anyone used SQLite before with asp.net?  Is there a SQLite Linq provider?  Do you recommend something other than SQLite?  Would like to hear your thoughts.

Will this work as the master database and then backup to a sql server 2005 db?  Can you run a hybrid of the two?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use SQLite at all if I don't have the need to rebuild the database each and every time I ran my code. Read more about [Asp.Net and SQLite here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)!